# Why Solr admin query page interprets UTF-8 as ISO-8859-1

Tags: encoding, utf-8, solr, iso-8859-1

I deploy a war to my Tomcat 6.0.35 on Win7 64bit and when I use full-interface query page (I mean form.jsp) in Solr Admin to query 2 Chinese character (say it's C1C2) , the debug info shows:

```
<lst name="debug">
  <str name="rawquerystring">æ°è</str>
  <str name="querystring">æ°è</str>
  <str name="parsedquery">NEWSID:æ°è</str>
  <str name="parsedquery_toString">NEWSID:æ°è</str>
...
```

You can see C1C2 becomes æ°è. I deploy same war file to Tomcat on Linux or on another Win7 64bit of my colleagues' computer, the encoding acts well. Does anyone know why and how can I avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The evil is **Win7's File Virtualization** feature. By default, Win7 will enable this feature on several well-known folders, e.g. Windows, Program Files, ProgramData, etc. The effect is that under some conditions, a file will have dual contents and this just happen to occur on my server.xml.

The workaround is clean things in '**c:\Users\<user account>\AppData\local\VirtualStore**'. The long-time solution is "Don't install Tomcat in these well-know folders. If you insist, be sure not to install-'n-uninstall too many times."

*~~~ How I find this problem (you may not need to see this) ~~~*

Two words: "Pure luck". When I use some xml editor to edit tomcat-users.xml and add a user 'test'. I restart Tomcat but can't login to use manager UI. I recheck tomcat-users.xml and see that user is indeed set. Even I uninstall-'n-install different version of Tomcat, login still fails.

Then I use notepad to edit tomcat-users.xml and I'm astonished to see it's the original version Tomcat has installed. After editing it with notepad and restart Tomcat, I can login now.

Very quickly, my thoughts flashes to server.xml and I use notepad to see it. Ah Ha! There's no *URIEncoding* attrbutes in connector tag. After fixing it, The problem is solved.

*Eiplog*

In my case, my xml editor and IE both show wrong version, but my other browers and notepad show correct version. I still don't know what algorithm does Win7 uses on File Virtualization, so I think workaround will live for a while.